# How do I write huffman code into compressed file?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, huffman-code

So I have made a proper binary tree for searching characters that appear in the text file, but I'm struggling with making compressed file. I have a buffer:

```
struct BitBuffer {
FILE* file; // Initialization skipped.
unsigned char buffer = 0;
unsigned count = 0;

void outputBit(unsigned char bit) {
     buffer <<= 1;         // Make room for next bit.
     if (bit) {
         buffer |= 1; // Set if necessary.
         count++;              // Remember we have added a bit.
     }
     if (count == 8) {
         fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file); //
         count = 0;
     }
}
```

but I don't know how to create a code for a particular character. I mean I don't know how to find the proper path to the leaf that contains the searched letter and how do I keep the correct code. This is a university project and I can't use data containers such as vector, queue, map etc.

Comment: does your text file needs to be unicode or it can be only ascii? Btw you had forgotten the curly brackets, see my edit.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL it can be only ascii

Comment: The problem you described doesn't seem related to the code you posted

Comment: I saw a method for outputting the trees once. Can't find the source document at the moment, I'll try to recount it. They used a recursive method on the tree-head. It called itself again anytime it encountered a branch. Taking the left branch meant that a certain bit-pattern was output before the node's value, while taking the right caused a different sequence to be emitted. Yet another (or 2) patterns were used to indicate that the branch has no more leafs and the output function should back-up to the next branch and then choose the other option. I'm probably getting something wrong here.

Comment: you should start by implementing your own https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue in c++

Comment: What method are you using to compress the file?  For example, do you want to use ZIP to compress your Huffman output?

Comment: We need more context to really be able to help you. It sounds like you've already built the Huffman tree - is that right? Can you show that part of the code including the declaration for the tree? Your code above looks pretty good for emitting bits, but you seem to only be outputting a bit when it is set. That's not right, the bit should be output (stored in the buffer) whether it's one or zero.